# Does HC-SR501 detect motion of objects (non-living things)

Tags: sensor, motion

I've 20 years of programming experience but not hardware involved and planning to start with raspberry pi just for fun.

Willing to do some testings with motion sensors and stepper motors. I've checked this motion sensor (HC-SR501) but all the tutorials I've watched are done with human motion. 
My plan is to detect motion of non-living things, objects.

Does HC-SR501 detect objects or is there some other kind of sensor?

**Edit (Link to the sensor)**

This is the sensor I refer to

[HC-SR501](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0140WFNYQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not given a link to the sensor so this is an assumption.

Assuming the HC-SR501 is an infra-red sensor it detects a **change in infra-red**, i.e. change in temperature.

If the objects you want to detect are different in temperature to the background seen by the sensor they will be detected.  Otherwise they will not.

Comment: I think there's only one `HC-SR501` sensor out there which is popular enough to have tutorials about it. So this is a correct answer, not just an assumption.